# How do you stop character in unity from overlapping with Platform?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

[image: Player keeps sinking into platform]

Hi, as you can see from the above image, my player sinks into my platform. This is because
the platform isn't a flat surface. How do I stop the player from sinking into my platform?

So far I have tried to use layers, but I don't think this works for 3D objects. This is my first time creating a 3D game.

UPDATE: I've added colliders to both objects, but it still sinks.

Comment: Can you show us the colliders?

Comment: You will probably laugh, but I haven't added colliders yet.

Comment: I think that would be a good place to start then. :)

Comment: Well you've added the colliders, but do they have rigidbodies?

Comment: @Robster96 yes they both have rigidbody components.

Answer (score 1):

Probably collider shape/placement. Possible reasons:

- one or more colliders are not the shape you think they are. (click edit collider on its component to visualize
- one or more colliders is set to isTrigger.
- Concave generated mesh colliders can have unexpected results.